# Is it possible to use BLE to tap two iPhones together and initiate a file transfer?

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

Similar to how S-Beam works on Galaxy phones, could I tap two iOS7 devices together and use the RSSI to initiate a file transfer. I would like to share a photo by touching another iPhone.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Iphone support.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

- It's possible to use BLE to communicate between two phones
- It's possible to use Core Motion to detect a "bump"

So, yes. Writing the code to do all of this is your job. Note that BLE has pretty low transfer rates. You might want to look at multi-peer networking to do device-to-device Wifi.

Comment: No "Bump." Just proximity, or RSSI strength.

Comment: RSSI is probably not a reliable enough indicator on its own.

Comment: BLE is not meant for file transfer, notifications sort of data is transferred in BLE, for file transfer you need to use classic BT

Comment: I highly recommend using the device-to-device WiFi as opposed to BLE (as mentioned by Tom).  BLE is just not meant to do that.  We have written code that transfers files via BLE [  we are sending the file to a device that only has a BLE radio :(   ], and the packets are limited to somewhere in the ballpark of 20 bytes per.  The highest transfer rates I've been able to achieve are around 750 bytes per second on the latest Google devices.